# Can't show the tabbar icon, even with size 30*30

Tags: iphone, icons, tabbar

I prepared some PNG icons, size 30*30, but with colors, not only black/white. The icons are OK when I want to display them on buttons.

It can't be shown in the tabbar.
I am wondering if the iphone only supports some simple icons (the black/white icons with lines).

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Comment: It is OK for displaying if I put some simple icons with only black/white lines. In addition, it works for system build-in icons.

Comment: Do you just get a blank tab, or a silhouette of the icon?

Comment: The effect is same with no icon.

Answer (score 4):

TabBar icons displayed in gray scale even if they are color, and iPhone uses the alpha channel for masking.

I recommend checking this site, most iPhone developers like it :

http://www.glyphish.com/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The alpha component of the image is all that is used to draw the icon on the tab bar. So you need to make sure your image has a alpha channel or it will either not show up or show up as a blank square in the tab bar.

This does mean that effectively only monochrome images can be used in the tab bar.

I'm not at my mac right now and I can't remember if it is 1.0 alpha or 0.0 alpha that shows up as white in the tab bar, or if you need to have a black or white background, but if you create an image with varying transparency it should be easy enough to work out.

Comment: I am new on the image processing. Do you have any ideas on how to change the alpha component of the image? Thanks

Comment: Most image editors will do this. Look for transparency or alpha or opacity in the controls. Any non-opaque drawing gives you an alpha component.